# For Pusher.com service how can I push data to a public channel and know if any connected clients received the message successfully?

Tags: javascript, web, websocket, pusher

I need to make sure that clients were able to receive messages so I can take action immediately if not.  Is there any way to determine that?

I know about webhooks but my concern is it may not be bulletproof if connections drop off about the time I'm sending data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply sending back a confirmation event with a specific client or message ID?